# Django REST: ContentNotRenderedError when checking JSON object before rendering

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model, `Note`, which has a class-based view. It is supposed to return a JSON object upon the appropriate query.

Before returning the object, however, I would like to check that the `user` field in the note object matches the user currently logged in. (Users should not be able to access Note objects that are not their own.) To do this, I tried rewriting the `get()` method, calling on `self.retrieve()` to inspect the object before returning it:

```
class NoteDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Note
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        current_user = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.id)
        note = self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if note.author is current_user:
            return note
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied('Note does not belong to authenticated user.')(author=current_user)
```

However, this returns a `ContentNotRenderedError` when run: **The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed.**

Is there a way for me to check the object before returning it? Must I find a workaround?

Comment: look at "custom permissions" here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions

Comment: I suppose you are speaking of django-rest-framework... if yes, add it to the tags.

Comment: Yes, thanks! And I have been looking at custom permissions, but wasn't sure if it was the best way to go, since all that's needed is a simple identity check.

Comment: Are you using a standard REST resource? what you must override is get_object() instead of get()

Comment: I could probably do it either way—`get()`, `delete()`, etc. all call `get_object()`. But I still need to be able to access that object's fields before returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential workaround is to redefine `get_queryset()`, rather than `get()` or `get_object()`. `get_queryset()` is the function that returns all objects of the relevant model; `get_object()` narrows down among these given the argument `pk`.

By overriding `get_queryset()`, you restrict the potential objects that `get_object()` can pick. Thus the set is already filtered at the time `get()` is called.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    current_user = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.id)

    # Must filter by author to prevent making everyone's notes public
    queryset = Note.objects.filter(author=current_user)

    return queryset
```